# User involvement by voting/ranking

Tags: user-expectation, user-centered-design, voting, ranking

I am trying to find a tool where I can allow users to vote on which features we should priorities to develop. Important is that I decide what ideas they should to be able to vote for and it could be nice if the users could rank the ideas.

Can you recommend a tool and what are your experiences?

It could be nice if it is integrable with Jira.

Answer (score 2):

Probably [UserVoice](https://www.uservoice.com/)?

I believe it [works with Jira through plugins](http://feedback.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/76849-does-uservoice-integrate-with-jira).

I have answered this, but if this the answer you wanted, then it is not a right question for this forum actually.

Comment: @merqei Do you have some experince with UserVoice? I have been looking at it and know about the plugin but i am not sure if i can disable the possibility to add ideas as user? Is it possible to "push" ideas/issues from jira to the UserVoice platform or is it the other way around (UserVoice to Jira)?

Comment: Sorry, but I have not worked with it. I have used it as a consumer of a certain number of apps. but never as an admin of the system. Can't help you there.

Answer (score 2):

[Getsatisfaction](https://getsatisfaction.com/corp/) is another similar application that allows you to involve users in the product design/development process. I have had experiences with both UserVoice and GetSatisfaction, but I think it is important to have a plan or strategy around how you want to implement user-driven product development because there is a substantial amount of investment required both from the operational and user engagement aspect to make it work. I would definitely not use it unless you are planning to dedicate a substantial amount of time and effort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree and that's why i am looking for an application where I can decide which ideas the users are allowed to vote for! We have a pool of hours dedicated to fix some of the users ideas every sprint - but if they have the possibility to both make the ideas and vote the most voted ideas would probably cost many many hours..

Comment: @SigneSkelgaard Some other related questions you might be interested in: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72315/how-to-evaluate-the-impact-or-satisfaction-of-users-for-user-driven-design-decis

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57800/design-and-development-team-experience-with-community-user-driven-feedback-platf